# Cant understand why I'm getting the ReferenceError

Tags: javascript

```
obj = [{name: 'Elie'},{name: 'Tim'},{name: 'Elie'}]
function addKeyAndValue(arr,key,value) {
    newOne = [];
    arr.forEach(function(val,i,arr){
        newOne.push(arr[i].key = value);
    });
    return newOne;
}
```

I'm trying to pass an array of objects with key and value to add, like so: addKeyAndValue(obj, isItawesome, true)

and then I expect to get something like:

```
[{name: 'Elie', isItawesome: true},{name: 'Tim', isItawesome: true},{name: 'Elie', isItawesome: true}]
```

but I'm getting an error... can anyone explain why am I getting it, please?

Comment: Please show us how you are calling the function. What is `isItawesome`?

Comment: @bugwheels94 I did... like so: `addKeyAndValue(obj, isItawesome, true)`. the `isItawesome` is a key(a new one) and the `true` is the value(new one)

Comment: can you show reference error? what does it say exactly?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have to use string, as key, so call your function in that way:

```
addKeyAndValue(obj, 'isItawesome', true)
```

Secondly, you are pushing a value, not an object to your array in that place:

```
newOne.push(arr[i].key = value);
```

Change it into:

```
newOne.push({...val, [key]: value})
```

If you want to make it even better:

```
function addKeyAndValue(arr, key, value){
  return arr.map(el => ({...el, [key]: value });
}
```

Comment: Is this some new JS or something? It's all new to me, thanks anyway... I'll dive into it.

Comment: this "..." is called spread operator, you can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function incorrectly. Do

```
addKeyAndValue(obj, 'isItawesome', true)
```

Note that `isItawesome` is a string not a variable so you need to wrap it inside quotes

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```js
obj = [{name: 'Elie'},{name: 'Tim'},{name: 'Elie'}]

var result = obj.map(function(el) {
  var o = Object.assign({}, el);
  o.isItawesome = true;
  return o;
})


console.log(result);
```